# how to refresh a JFrame at every step of a program instead of opening a new JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

right now my code opens a new JFrame at every step of my program changing, I want this JFrame to instead, just to refresh. The data is supposed to show a predator prey simulation in which minnows eat algae and sharks eat the minnows and the sharks and minnows move around and eat each other. I have already set up a way for this to work, but i need help with this representation of the data i already have.

Edit: right now I have images on buttons to represent each of the three and the way they move is to refresh the buttons with new images.

```
JFrame frame=new JFrame(); //creates frame
JButton[][] grid; //names the grid of buttons
int width = Model.getGrid().length;
int length = Model.getGrid()[0].length;
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(width,length)); //set layout
    grid=new JButton[width][length]; //allocate the size of grid
    int size = Model.getGameModel().copyOfActors().size();

    for(int y=0; y<length; y++){
            for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
                size = Model.getGameModel().copyOfActors().size();
                //don't think this for loop is written correctly. See if there is an actor with location == grid[x][y] and if not put a *
                //shouldn't need this for loop at all
                boolean foundAnActor = false;
                for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {
                        if(Model.getGameModel().copyOfActors().get(i).getX() == x && Model.getGameModel().copyOfActors().get(i).getY() == y && foundAnActor == false)
                        {
                            grid[x][y] = new JButton(new ImageIcon (Model.getGameModel().copyOfActors().get(i).image)); //this should put the image on the button

                            foundAnActor = true;
                        }
                }
                if(foundAnActor == false)
                {
                            grid[x][y]=new JButton(String.valueOf(Controller.stepsTaken)  ); //creates new button 
                }
                    frame.add(grid[x][y]); 
                    //tried to add a frame
            }
    }
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack(); //sets appropriate size for frame
    frame.setVisible(true); //makes frame visible
        // tried to add a frame
```

Comment: Representing data how? As an animating image? You don't show any graphics in your code. As a changing UI interface? As updating data? Please improve this question, as it smells of being an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) type question -- i.e., you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: ................hello?

Comment: not as an animated image but updating the buttons so that each one shows a different image on a different step. The sharks, minnows and algae all have a corresponding image that shows up on different buttons, they also move and do specific actions each step. I have it set up right now to where it works, but say, for 5 steps it will open 5 windows and for 10 steps it will open 10 windows. My problem stems from this and my question is how, if possible, I could get this onto one JFrame instead of 5 or 10, thanks so much btw.

Comment: and I told you in the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you appear to be displaying state as ImageIcons in JButtons, and are going about it wrong. Don't create new JButtons, new JFrames, instead create an array of JButtons and when the state of your model changes, simply iterate through this array, changing the state JButtons by calling `setIcon(...)` on the JButton passing in the appropriate Icon based on the model state.